# Замена текста на странице без селектора на js/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью js/JQuery найти на странице текст и заменить его на другой без селекторов, к примеру где то на странице есть текст:

TEXT_1 который надо заменить на TEXT_2, есть ли какой то способ это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

использовать **[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** например.

```js
var text = $('.post-text');
var replaced = text.html().replace(/TEXT_1/gi, 'TEXT_2');
text.html(replaced);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">

  <p>Как с помощью js/JQuery найти на странице текст и заменить его на другой без селекторов, к примеру где то на странице есть текст:</p>

  <p>TEXT_1 который надо заменить на TEXT_2, есть ли какой то способ это сделать?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказал Алексей, без метода [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) тут не обойтись, приведу немного другой пример (возможно не самый эстетически красивый, но имеющий место быть в качестве примера):

```js
function replaceText() {
  // берем тело документа, найдем каждый элемент на нем и для каждого вызовем функцию
  $(document.body).find('*').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text(); // берем текст текущего элемента
    text = text.replace(/111/g, "222"); // заменяем необходимое
    $(this).text(text); // выставляем новый текст в элемент
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Hello world! I want to replace '111' to '222'. Can do you help me?</p>
  <div>
    I am '111'! Replace me!
  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="replaceText();">Replace text...</button>
</body>
```

Думаю, также будет полезно ознакомиться с [флагами в регулярных выражениях](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-introduction#%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8).

> '`g`' - если этот флаг есть, то ищются все совпадения, иначе – только первое.